When clicking on hamburger menu nothing happens
I'm creating responsive navbar for my website, and I came across to this simple looking problem. Whenever I'm clicking on hamburger menu icon nothing happens. My idea is -- whenever hamburger icon is clicked, menu appear/disappear, I even made transition in CSS line 75 (transition: all .5s;)
I tried to go over my code multiple times, and I still don't see reason why is this not working. Here is my HTML and CSS code (with checkbox, I tried to avoid using JS for now):
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Test</title>  
      <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a4b0d61691.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <input type="checkbox" id="check">
            <label for="check" class="checkbtn">
                <i class="fas fa-bars" area-hidden="true"></i>
            </label>
            <label class="logo">Test</label>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://localhost/list">Test1</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://localhost/about">Test2</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://localhost/faq">Test3</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://localhost/contact">Test4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>

*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    font-family: "Roboto","Arial",sans-serif;
}
nav{
    background: #4287f5;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
}
label.logo{
    color: white;
    font-size: 35px;
    line-height: 80px;
    padding: 0 100px;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}
nav ul{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 80px;
    margin: 0 5px;
}
nav ul li a{
    color: white;
    font-size: 17px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
a.active,a:hover{
    background: #57aef2;
    transition: .5s;
}
.checkbtn{
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;
    float: right;
    line-height: 80px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}
#check{
    display: none;
}
@media (max-width: 952px){
    label.logo{
        font-size: 30px;
        padding-left: 50px;
    }
    nav ul li a{
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 858px){
    .checkbtn{
        display: block;
    }
    ul{
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        background: #1b354a;
        top: 80px;
        left: 0;
        text-align: center;
        transition: all .5s;
    }
    nav ul li{
        display: block;
        margin: 50px 0;
        line-height: 30px;
    }
    nav ul li a{
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    a:hover,a.active{
        background: none;
        color: #57aef2;
    }
    #check:checked ~ ul{
        left: 0;
    }
}

I would really appreciate working answer, since I'm dealing with this problem for some time. Thanks in advance :)

You forgot a left: -100% at the ul.


    *{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    font-family: "Roboto","Arial",sans-serif;
}
nav{
    background: #4287f5;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
}
label.logo{
    color: white;
    font-size: 35px;
    line-height: 80px;
    padding: 0 100px;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}
nav ul{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 80px;
    margin: 0 5px;
}
nav ul li a{
    color: white;
    font-size: 17px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
a.active,a:hover{
    background: #57aef2;
    transition: .5s;
}
.checkbtn{
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;
    float: right;
    line-height: 80px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}
#check{
    display: none;
}
@media (max-width: 952px){
    label.logo{
        font-size: 30px;
        padding-left: 50px;
    }
    nav ul li a{
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 858px){
    .checkbtn{
        display: block;
    }
    ul{
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        background: #1b354a;
        top: 80px;
        left: -100%;
        text-align: center;
        transition: all .5s;
    }
    nav ul li{
        display: block;
        margin: 50px 0;
        line-height: 30px;
    }
    nav ul li a{
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    a:hover,a.active{
        background: none;
        color: #57aef2;
    }
    #check:checked ~ ul{
        left: 0;
    }
}
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a4b0d61691.js"></script>

      <nav>
          <input type="checkbox" id="check">
          <label for="check" class="checkbtn">
              <i class="fas fa-bars" area-hidden="true"></i>
          </label>
          <label class="logo">Test</label>
          <ul>
              <li><a href="http://localhost/list">Test1</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://localhost/about">Test2</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://localhost/faq">Test3</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://localhost/contact">Test4</a></li>
          </ul>
      </nav>




Thanks a lot, I simply overlooked it :D
